# ISPConfig keeps giving me a 404 Not Found on Ubuntu/Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I recently installed NGinX on Ubuntu 14 and also installed **ISPConfig**.
I did everything that was needed to use ISPConfig,
but the url keeps saying "404 Not Found".

Here is my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ispconfig.vhost:

```
server {
        listen 8080;
                ssl off;

        server_name _;

        root   /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/web/;

        client_max_body_size 20M;

        location / {
               index index.php index.html;
        }
        location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt)$ {
           access_log        off;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
               try_files $uri =404;
               include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
               fastcgi_pass unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/ispconfig.sock;
               fastcgi_index index.php;
               fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
               fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
               fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
               fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
               fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        }

        location ~ /\. {
               deny  all; } }
```

I worked on it for a while now and couln't find the solution..

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

I was calling the wrong URL, my bad.

I stated 8080/ispconfig/ at the end of the url, while it only needed domainname:8080

Sorry for inconvenience, hope someone else can resolve the same issue..